# Yahoo mail rejects my mails - Error 554 Message not allowed

Tags: email, yahoo

I need some help with a problem I'm facing with Yahoo mail. To summarize, here's my situation:

I have a simple e-commerce site with some users signed up. Some of them, uses Yahoo mail. When they buy an item, an email is automatically sent to them with the purchase details and a link to: https://example.com/item/item_id.

I used outgoing SMTP GMail server. The problem: Yahoo (only Yahoo) is rejecting my emails. The reason: **"554 Message not allowed - [PH01] Email not accepted for policy reasons. Please visit https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN5067.html [120]"**. I have this same issue if I try to send an email with a link to my site even directly from a Yahoo mail.

Searching in Yahoo forums, I found [this post](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Temporary-Errors/Error-554/td-p/127237), in which the user who ask, has the same problem, but the moderator of the site gives a solution that (to me) doesn't make much more sense.

Does anyone have an idea of what can I do? I need to be able to send mails because I'm in production and I need this mails.

I will be so gracefully for your help!

Regards!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is for *programing* questions. While email deliverability problems sometimes involve some amount of back-end work, we can't and really mustn't help you get past spam filters. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam

Answer (score 2):

It's because Yahoo thinks the email you sent was a phishing attempt. Try sending a simple email with nothing fancy and see if it goes through. Theirs's probably something in the HTML it doesn't like.

Comment: I can send email in general... I didn't mention in the question, but I changed my site to an HTML only page saying nothing and send the link in an email but it was rejected again... Just to verify if something in my site generates the problem, but it seems no... :/

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.Yahoo  rejects email if you use any numeric value in email URls like (444email.png) or any image name with numeric values.